# Postgres unable to parse new value in jsonb_set when running command externally from outside container

Tags: linux, database, postgresql, bash, podman

I'm attempting to update a jsonb value in my postgres database externally.

I know that this sql query works when executing internally in psql but when running externally it seems postgres is having a hard time parsing the new value "password123" as jsonb.

The command I'm running is

```
/opt/application/usr/postgresql/bin/psql -U postgres -d database1 -c "UPDATE system_settings SET search_settings = jsonb_set(search_settings, '{application,local,user,admin,password}', '"password123"');"
```

but I'm facing the error

```
DETAIL:  Token "password123" is invalid.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: password123
```

I've tried to force postgres to recognise that the new value is jsonb via

```
/opt/application/usr/postgresql/bin/psql -U postgres -d database1 -c "UPDATE system_settings SET search_settings = jsonb_set(search_settings, '{application,local,user,admin,password}', '"password123"'::jsonb);"
```

but this doesn't work either.

Are there other ways to force psql to recognise the value as jsonb?
Or alternative sql commands to perform the same requirement?

Edit: turned out to just be a quoting issue thanks to @Laurenz Albe

the command

```
/opt/application/usr/postgresql/bin/psql -U postgres -d database1 -c "UPDATE system_settings SET search_settings = jsonb_set(search_settings, '{application,local,user,admin,password}', '\"password123\"');"
```

Did the trick.

Now I'm attempting to add another layer as this commands needs to be executed within a container which means more quotes...

I'm currently running

```
podman exec application su postgres -c "/opt/application/usr/postgresql/bin/psql -U postgres -d database1 -c \"UPDATE system_settings SET search_settings = jsonb_set(search_settings, '{application,local,user,admin,password}', '\"password123\"');\""
```

which again is resulting in

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
LINE 1: ...h_settings, '{application,local,user,admin,password}', 'password1...
                                                                  ^
DETAIL:  Token "password123" is invalid.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: password123
```

Comment: This is just a bash quoting problem.

Comment: Ah yeah you're right thanks, I've escaped the quotes in the new value which worked. Now trying to add another layer of executing within a container which is causing me a similar issue, i presume more quoting issues.